# val undefined with BootstrapDialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-dialog

I'm using library BootstrapDialog, in my page I have an input field like that:

```
<div id="divtoload" style="display: none;">     
    <div align="center">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="100px">input:</td>
                <td align="left"><input id="inputText" name="inputText" type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the same page I have:

```
$("#link").click(function()   { 
    var element = $('<div></div>').load('index.html #divtoload', function() {
        element.find('#divtoload').show();
    }); 

    BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Recovery',
            message: element,
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Send',
                cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                action: function(){
                    console.log($("#inputText").val());
                 }
            }]

    })
})
```

But the console.log says that inputText is undefined.

Comment: I guess input text not exists yet when `BootstrapDialog.show` is called

Comment: @LucasCosta the input field is inside a div element which is loaded into the dialog. (the dialog is opened by clicking on a link)

Comment: Can you pleas give us more of your HTML, because when I try to reproduce you problem on my own I do not get the error-message

Comment: It still works as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/ctzd581q/

Comment: @Zorken17 i put the whole code of bootstrapdialog

Comment: I don't think its saying undefined. It just doesn't give a value coz you haven't given it one. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ctzd581q/1/

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's 'load' method is asynchronous, meaning the JS will not wait for it to complete before running the BootstrapDialog code. Consequently, it will not have returned the HTML and loaded it before creating the dialog.

Putting the dialog code inside the callback should fix it:

```
$("#link").click(function()   { 
var element = $('<div></div>').load('index.html #divtoload', function() {
    element.find('#divtoload').show();

    BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Recovery',
            message: element,
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Send',
                cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                action: function(){
                    console.log($("#inputText").val());
                 }
            }]

    })


}); 

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

It was happening a strange things, BootstrapDialog was not using the div I defined but a copy of it